# Bright, brief light in sky this morning (daytime) - satellite flare?

Tags: satellite, flare

This morning at 8:00am UK time, give or take about 3 minutes, I saw a very bright light in the sky which seemed to get a little brighter, lasting for maybe 5 seconds after I first noticed it, then faded out to nothing for a few seconds, then came back for another few seconds and disappeared entirely.

I was at around the following co-ordinates, and I was looking towards the South:

Lat: 51.980619 Long: -0.8443739614449441

I'd say it was at something like 30 degrees inclination but that's a really rough guess. It was somewhere around a third to half way between the horizon and overhead.

I know there are duplicate questions about this kind of thing BUT I believe this is different because:

- I saw it during daylight. The sun was up, albeit behind clouds.
- The light was VERY bright, when I first saw it I thought it was Venus but then it obviously faded out. I think it was probably even brighter than Venus would have been.
- I have already ruled out Iridium flares by looking at Heavens Above. I have seen Iridium flares once or twice before and I think it looked similar.

Presumably there aren't too many objects in the sky that can get that bright. Are there any other objects which I could track apart from Iridium sats? Can anybody else find anything it might have been?

Comment: Can you rule out a plane?

Comment: Yes. Far too bright to be a plane and I know how planes flash. It wasn't a steady flashing either it was one light of a few seconds, fade out (not blink out) to nothing, then growing from nothing to very bright again, then disappeared. Also since it was daylight, if it were a plane I'd likely have been able to see the plane itself or at least its contrails.

Comment: I was thinking of reflections off the wings. I was once puzzled for a minute until I realised I was looking at aircraft landing lights, but the declination was not so high. Was it moving like an iridium?

Comment: Various possibilities here: [The Unidentified Aerospace Phenomena (UAP)  Observations Reporting Scheme](http://www.uapreporting.org/?page_id=222).